# GridView Table with static column names

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp

So I want to create a table like GridView control with static column names. I can add my grid columns or rows dynamicly with no problem via the ItemTemplate. The problem now is, when I try to add a static grid with columndefinitions to my GridView i cannot see it. Do you know why?

here is my xaml code: (the grid which is not seen is marked)

```
<GridView Margin="10" Name="GridViewAllgemein" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ausstattung}" BorderBrush="Black" IsTapEnabled="True" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <Grid Background="Red" Height="50"> //cannot see this grid
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> //cannot see this grid
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/> //cannot see this grid
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/> //cannot see this grid
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/> //cannot see this grid
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/> //cannot see this grid
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> //cannot see this grid
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Test"></TextBlock> //cannot see this grid
        </Grid> //cannot see this grid
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Ausstattung">
                <Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" Height="40" Margin="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind Beschreibung}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind Ausgabedatum}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind Rückgabedatum}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="3" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind Anzahl}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

this is the result [image]

Comment: Why are you using the Grid inside the GridView, wouldn't it work if you use Grid just above GridView in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem now is, when I try to add a static grid with
>   columndefinitions to my GridView i cannot see it. Do you know why?

This is because GridView is an ItemsControl and it cannot contain child elements directly.

> It must have items in its Items collection before it can show
>   anything on the screen. To populate the view, you can add items
>   directly to the Items collection, or set the ItemsSource property to a
>   data source. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview)

As @Ipsit Gaur pointed out in a comment, in this case one option is to put the Grid with the Header before the GridView, since GridView itself does not have a contept for creating a Header.

Btw. telerik opensourced its UWP controls and in some cases you can use it for free. They have a [Grid control with a built in functionality for this](http://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui/grid).

Syncfusion also has a similar community licence with [a similar control called SfDataGrid](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sfdatagrid/getting-started)

*I'm not trying to advertise products, I just list free controls you can potentially use to solve your problem.

Comment: Very good answer thank you for this. I didnt knew this before. Do you know how I can bind the width of my new grid above the gridview to the width of the gridview?

Comment: Got it, I just put the grid and the gridview in a stackpanel. Thank you for your help

Comment: Great, I was about to make a sample for that, but in this case I can skip that work... Thanks for the accept!

Comment: I mean i wouldnt blame you, if you know a better way then adding it to a stackpanel, because it is not exactly the same width, for some reason .. but thank you anyways :P